# ImageView not able to show high resolution images

Tags: android, image, imageview

I am accessing images from android resources folder.
i am using asynctask to load images.

On first time i used images with resolution of 1024*768 the app opens and one by one image is shown into  imageview.

on second time, 
For experiment i used images with resoltion 1920*1080 the app is giving runtime error and force closed.
The same happens with image resoltion of 1280*720.

but it perfactly runs with 1024*768 resolution
why this happens????

i m not posting code cause it doesn't seem to have programatical issue.

Comment: If it doesn't have "programatically issue" then it doesn't belong to SO.

Comment: @Mighter it is `programatical issue` although OP said it is not. Simply he got OOM.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: it shows out of memory but my question is why this happens with hd resoltion???

Comment: it's because you're out of memory. That's the reason for "out of memory error". Because high resolution images uses more memory than smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you got `Out Of Memory exception` because your image size is large, consider this calculation:

In order to show each pixel in `ARGB_8888` we use 4 bytes so:

```
your first  image: 1024 * 768 * 4 = 2MB 
your second image: 1920 * 1080* 4 = 6MB
your third  image: 1280 * 720 * 4 = 3MB
```

I do not know how many images you are loading to your `RAM` but your `RAM` is limited and it is at least `16MB` so with other 4-5 images you will have no `RAM` to other objects. look at

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to solve your issue.